# Can the triangle function approximate the Gaussian curve for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, approximation-theory

I was thinking about approximating the Gaussian curve with a triangular curve. The graphs look like this:

[image]

their respective functions are:

$$ y_1(x) = t(x) = max(0, 1 - |x|)$$

$$ y_2(x) = e^{ - x^2}$$

where the domain $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I wanted to do something (potentially crazy) and use that approximation (or something of that sort that made this work) but with complex numbers.

So the idea is if I have a complex number $ z = re^{i \theta} \in \mathbb{C}$ to (somehow) use the approximation:

$$ e^{-|x|^2} = \phi(x) \approx t(x) = max(0, 1 - |x|) \approx re^{i \theta} = z$$

So the intuition (that might be completely wrong) is that because complex numbers can be expressed using the exponential function, maybe can they be expressed using $ e^{-|x|^2}$ and hence, some for of the triangle function?

Comment: That's not really what people usually mean by "the exponential function" -- what you've got there is a Gaussian distribution (or "normal distribution" or "bell-shaped cuve").

Comment: @mweiss yes, oops got a little exited about my question and used a wrong term. I will re-phrase in a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "approximated"? Can you make this more specific?

Comment: Since your function depends only on $|z|$, rather than on $z$, you are really just dealing with a real-valued argument, so I don't see why this wouldn't work just fine.

Comment: @mweiss I think you are right...like me think about it a bit more what I exactly had in mind.

Comment: That's a really bad approximation, by most standards.

Comment: @RobertIsrael sorry if this a very basic question, but if you don't mind, could you provide what standards you are talking about? I've been interested for a while now to think about how good an approximation this is but lacked the knowledge to reason about this in a precise/rigorous way.

Comment: I'm not sure what standards Robert has in mind, but it seems to me that at the very least you could make the triangle wider so that it is tangent to the curve at the curve's inflection points; that would close the gap between the curve and the straight segments.  Alternatively you might want to make the triangle even wider still, so that part of it extends beyond the curve; if you choose your parameters wisely you can make it so that the amount by which the triangle overestimates the curve in one region is equal to the amount by which it underestimates the curve in another.

Comment: Along similar lines, you could choose the width of the triangle such that the area under the triangular function is equal to the area below the Gaussian curve.

Comment: You might try an $L^p$ norm, for example.